# Grab city info using jQuery Json from Wikipedia api

Tags: jquery

This is the URL that I wanna grab info from

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=boston&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1

I want to grab the `extract`

And this is my code, using `Boston` as an example

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=boston&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1", function(data) {
    console.log(data.extract);
})
```

But nothing shows in the console, not even if I change `data.extract` to some random text.

I am now getting this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=boston&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you sure there is an extract property. What happens when you console.log just data?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there's an `extract` property, you can visit the URL and make sure yourself. Nothing happens when I just outputs `data`

Comment: Are you getting an error? I am getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=boston&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1&_=1458832010491. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access. This makes sense because your are trying to do a cross-site request

Comment: extract could be accessed with: data.query.pages.extract if is a json... but usually is better to extract info from http://wiki.dbpedia.org/

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier you're right. After some fiddling I am getting this error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it if anyone's interested

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var CityURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=boston&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1&callback=?';

        $.getJSON(CityURL ,function(data) {
            $.each(data.query.pages, function(i, item) {
                console.log(item.extract);

                $('div#details').html(item.extract);
            });
        });
    });
```